# From PHP to Play Framework with Scala server

Tags: php, scala, playframework

I am re-writing an application in Scala with Play Framework. The original code is in PHP, which I have no experience. Within the server side there are many code lines like:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
$pathInfo = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$_SERVER['If-Modified-Since']
$_SERVER['If-None-Match'].
```

I want to convert these into Scala statements. In play framework I thought the map within the request object in any given controller will do it but it does not. How can I implement this ?

Comment: It's hard to guess what your code need to do, jump into PHP docs anyway: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: @biesior Well it returns image files and if not modified returns them from the cache instead of the server basically

Answer (score 0):

For the query string and path info I found in request.headers which returns a map where you can find different mappings. Query string is also directly returned by request.queryString.
However the other two I still could not find

Comment: it just checks if header with that name is available, so check againts the `request.headers` as well see usecase in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10847262/1066240