# PHP's HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH is always empty

Tags: php

PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` is *always* empty however Firefox's Web Developer Network Requests tab shows the *request header* as being `If-Modified-Since: "Tue, 27 Jun 2017 09:08:23 GMT"`. Cache is *not* disabled and my `.htaccess` file contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]
```

How do I get PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` to return the request header properly *or* how do I access that request header in an alternative manner? I came across `getenv('HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE')` though that didn't return anything either. Is it possible there is something in the `php.ini` file that needs to be changed? It is a fairly fresh server setup.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847157/handling-if-modified-since-header-in-a-php-script

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `If-None-Match` http header to your server. If you do so the `HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH` server variable should contain the value of the set `If-None-Match` header.

```
curl http://my/endpoint --header 'If-None-Match: "my-custom-etag-value"'
```

Comment: Could you please use standard terms like client and server? Also I'm *not* using cURL for this, it's a request in a browser.

Comment: Sure, but how should I explain this for some random http clients?

Comment: Okay, so if I need to send an `If-None-Match` *request header* how do I get PHP and a *browser* to do this? What specifically triggers that? As in not using cURL (as fun as cURL can be).

Comment: Wait do you want to handle this manually or for static responses/files? Or maybe an api?

Comment: The request is to a PHP file that determines the `filemtime()` of the actual file where data is stored. So I suppose the answer is yes, I have to do this manually.