# .htaccess url-rewrite if file not exists - how to deal with favicon.ico?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mysqli

I'm building my own URL shortening website and I use this as my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /go.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This should redirect any URL (that is not a file) to `go.php`, for the URL redirection.

The problem is:

When I go to `example.com/keyword`, I get the `go.php` page. Then, I extract the keyword with:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$keyword = strtok($url, '?');
$keyword = ltrim($keyword,"/");
```

Then I insert the current keyword and its referrer (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER]`) to the `log` table in the database.

Everything seems to work just fine, but in my log table there are two new rows instead of one: one with the correct keyword `example`, and one with the keyword `favicon.ico` and `http://example.com/keyword` as the referrer.

What's exactly happening here? I need only the first and correct row. Does this problem happen only with `favicon.ico`? How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your browser requests the `favicon.ico`-file, just after the request. If it exists it will use it as the icon in your browser-tab (for example that neat little stackoverflow-icon).

As it doesn't exists on your server that request will pass all rewrite-conditions. Simple add an extra condition to ignore (not forward to go.php) the favicon-request.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /go.php [L]
```

Proof of concept: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=f2fa97da-14b9-5c2e-8c58-c2c620b35c76

Bonus tip, to ignore all `.ico`, `.jpg`, `.css` etc (my favorite rewrite-rule):

```
 RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$ /go.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi - I can see you have a better idea about htaccess than I do :). I am doing similar operations as OP, but have looked at how WordPress does it. They have a pretty powerful rewrite engine, where you can have pretty permalinks (basically urls like `/thing/another-thing` instead of `?param=value&another=value`. Their htaccess is not including any special cases for favicon, or else. Only this https://pastebin.com/1SWBy81X is present. So I am wondering why "the world" needs to add each exception (favicon, etc), while they don't - there _must_ be something we miss?

Answer (score 0):

The `favicon.ico` request is a another request than `example.com/keyword`. it is requested automatically by the browser, the browser has the control of how the `favicon.ico` request is going to be. for example the referer header of the request could be the main request URL that triggered the `favicon.ico` like what happened with you, or it might be empty. This is how the the `favicon.ico` request is logged in my database. Notice how Firefox requested the file with an empty `referer` header

[image]

**How to deal with that request on the server side**

you have several options here

1- you can exclude the file from the rewrite rule as [@Peter van der Wal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2903251/peter-van-der-wal) said in his answer.

2- you can serve the file yourself with PHP (I will not do that), for example you can do something like this

```
<?php
$iconFile ="some-media-directory/cool-icon.php";
$fileSize = filesize($iconFile);
$fHandle = fopen($iconFile,"rb");
header("Content-Type: image/ico");
$lastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s ', filemtime($logoFile)) . 'GMT';
header("Last-Modified: $lastModified");
header("Content-Disposition: inline");
header("Content-Length: $fileSize");
die(fread($fHandle,$fileSize));
```

If you are going to serve the file yourself in PHP, then you have to manage the cashe headers. Please see this question ([Handling If-modified-since header in a PHP-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847157/handling-if-modified-since-header-in-a-php-script))